# Перевод четных символов в верхний регистр

Tags: java

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая принимает на вход строку, а выводит ее же, но четные символы в верхнем регистре.
Пытаюсь, ковыряюсь, не выходит...Накалякал что-то вот подобное, но не работает >.<

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Фраза");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = in.nextLine();
    char[] symb = input.toCharArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < symb.length; i++) {

           if (symb[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(Character.toLowerCase(symb[i]));
            }
           else if (symb[i] % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.print(Character.toUpperCase(symb[i]));
            }
        }

}
```

}

Ввод: привет
Вывод: пРиВеТ
Ну или наоборот, значения не имеет

Comment: Так вы не `symb[i] % 2` проверяйте, а `i % 2`. Вам же не четность кода символа нужно проверить, а четность буквы по счету от начала строки.

Comment: господи, точно, вот я балбес. спасибо!

Comment: Кроме того, у вас нечётные символы принудительно переводятся в нижний регистр, так и задумано?